# SQL Server order by part of string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

One of my tables have values like this..

```
Year 1
Year 9
Year 4
Kindy [can be any word without numbers]
Pre-School [can be any word without numbers]
Year 8
Year 22
Year 15....
```

How can I select Them in alphabetically first and then by numerically in ascending order like this..

```
Kindy [can be any word without numbers]
Pre-School [can be any word without numbers]
Year 1
Year 4
Year 8
Year 9
Year 15
Year 22
```

I could not extract the integer and order in this case as some of the years don't have it..

**UPDATE**

MY ANSWER -- MISSING DISTINCT

```
SELECT  YearLevel FROM Student 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN YearLevel NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 0
ELSE CAST(RIGHT(YearLevel, LEN(YearLevel) - 5) AS int)
END
```

Comment: In this scenario simple order by clause will work very fine. You must try that

Comment: No, it won't sort correctly. Year 15 will appear immediately after year 1 -- To get it to sort correctly, you have to interpret the numeric portion as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT YearLevel FROM student
GROUP BY YearLevel 
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN YearLevel LIKE 'Year%'
        THEN 'Year' + CONVERT(varchar,LEN(YearLevel)) + YearLevel
        ELSE YearLevel
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN col = 'Kindy' then 0
WHEN col = 'Pre-School' then 1
ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(col,6,LEN(col)) AS INT) + 1
END
```

Comment: What do you mean primary schools? Can you please edit your question and add **ALL** the relevant information such as the table structure and sample input and output there?

Comment: Hi shree, I meant any names apart from 'Year..'. I have posted an update.. Im getting there just need distinct records..

Comment: Are you saying you have data like 'Class 3' apart from 'Year 3'? Your update does not make that clear still.

Comment: I have updated my question again.. only the first two years have any names... Kindy [can be anything]
Pre-School [[can be anything].. the rest of year levels have same names as I mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

In first you must create following function for get text part and number part of your string :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumbersFromText](@String varchar(2000))
RETURNS INT 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0,
            @IntNumbers VARCHAR(1000) = '',
            @FindNumber BIT = 0

    WHILE @Count <= LEN(@String) BEGIN

        IF SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) >= '0' AND SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) <= '9' BEGIN
            SET @IntNumbers = @IntNumbers + SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1)
            SET @FindNumber = 1
        END ELSE IF (@FindNumber = 1) BEGIN
            BREAK
        END
        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
    RETURN CAST(@IntNumbers AS INT)
END



CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTextPartOfText](@String varchar(2000))
RETURNS INT 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0,
            @Text VARCHAR(1000) = '',           

    WHILE @Count <= LEN(@String) BEGIN

        IF SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) >= '0' AND SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) <= '9' BEGIN
            BREAK
        END ELSE BEGIN
            SET @Text = @Text + SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1)
        END
        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
    RETURN @Text
END
```

In second you use following query for your sort:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY [dbo].[GetTextPartOfText](TextColumn),[dbo].[GetNumbersFromText](TextColumn), TextColumn
```

Comment: Why create a function when inbuilt functions will work?

Comment: @Mehdi.. That's too complex way to do and not the solution im looking for